# using c# arraylist.binarysearch with custom objects

Tags: c#, arraylist

please note, I know the ArrayList is old...etc but I need to know and understand how it works, so please bear with me (btw, not sure if I spelt bear wrog, i forgot how to spell it...xD)

I am writing a test tomorrow (im in university), but I am at a dead end with this problem, I love sorting out problems but i just cant find any solution for this one...

say I have:

```
class Person 
{
    private string name, surname;
    private int age, year born;
    //with more variables, etc...
```

and I have another class

```
Class People
{
    ArrayList arlPeople = new ArrayList();
}
```

I know the code isnt of any working order but it is just to make my question more clear

Okay so I would like to know, the user enters a name

```
Console.Writeline("display all dat of the person by entering their name >>")
```

and so the user enter's the name, BUT...

since the arraylist offers a `.sort()` and a `.binarysearch()`, I would like to find the position of the person whose name has been entered by using the binary search method

the Binary Search requires a parameter `(Object value)`, but how do I pass the user entered name as a object parameter???

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
class NameComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        var xs = (Swimmer)x;
        var ys = (Swimmer)y;
        return xs.Name.CompareTo(ys.Name);
    }
}
class Swimmer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Swimmers
{
    ArrayList AllSwimmers;
    IComparer nameComparer = new NameComparer();

    public Swimmers()
    {
        AllSwimmers = new ArrayList();
        AllSwimmers.Add(new Swimmer { Name = "Tom" });
        AllSwimmers.Add(new Swimmer { Name = "Joe" });
        AllSwimmers.Add(new Swimmer { Name = "George" });
        AllSwimmers.Sort(nameComparer);
    }

//some other methods in between

    public int GetOnName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the swimmer");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        int pos = AllSwimmers.BinarySearch(new Swimmer { Name = name }, nameComparer);

        Console.WriteLine(pos);

        return pos;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Person` object could implement `IComparable`. That is, you need to add a `compareTo` method that compares the name:

```
class Person : IComparable
{
    private string name, surname;
    private int age, year born;

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        return name.compareTo((obj as Person).name);
    }

    ...
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it, but I followed your example of avoiding generics. If you do this you should probably override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` as well.

Tim S. has a good answer that uses `IComparer` instead. Thinking about it, it could make more sense depending on whether you think `Person`s are intrinsically comparable or just able to be compared.

Comment: But how do you go about resolving the index of the person object given the name of the person alone? I believe that is his question.

Comment: @ByteBlast It is an ugly solution, but you can instantiated a new `Person` with the required `name` and just perform the search with it.